# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined at insertDocuments at insertOne

Tags: mongodb, express

I was trying to insert a record into a collection when this error was thrown. I went through the mongodb doc on [insertOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/) and I understand that mongod will automatically add the _id when it is not specified as in my case, so I'm wondering why there is an undefined id error.

Here's the code I'm working with, first the api route and the data I'm trying to insert

```
app.post('/api/contacts', (req, res) => {
// retrieve the user being added in the body of the request
const user = req.body;

// obtain a reference to the contacts collection
const contactsCollection = database.collection('contacts');

// insert data into the collection
contactsCollection.insertOne(user, (err, r) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({error: 'Error inserting new record.'});
    }

    const newRecord = r.ops[0];

    return res.status(201).json(newRecord);
});
});
```

The json data for inserting

```
{
"name": "Wes Harris",
"address": "289 Porter Crossing, Silver Spring, MD 20918",
"phone": "(862) 149-8084",
"photoUrl": "/profiles/wes-harris.jpg"
}
```

Database connection to the to the database hosted on mlab is successful with no errors. What could possibly be wrong here and how do I go about fixing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message means that the object that you are passing into insertOne is undefined (and hence it can’t read the _id property of of it). You might like to look at what exactly req.body contains as that is what is passed as user. (I don’t know TypeScript but, in node/express, I have had errors like this when I didn’t set up bodyParser correctly)

Comment: I took advice to look at what the `req.body` was sending by commenting everything below `const user = req,body` out then added `return res.json(user)` and tested a post with postman and user wasn't defined like you suggested as nothing came up. So the question now is how do I get user defined? Any idea?

Comment: What form is the body that you are expecting (postman lets you use either of form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded, raw, binary), then make sure that you've set up body-parser appropriately, if indeed you are using body-parser. (I usually cut and paste the setup and sometimes it is wrong for the new use and I get undefined req.body).

Comment: Eventually found a solution to it. By setting the app to use body-parser

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem. Solved and it by using body-parser and then parsing the json object being sent as follows:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse application/json
app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```